# Mostrar um número em 2 casas decimais

Tags: javascript

Como faço o cálculo de um `input` (valor inteiro) e uma variável em moeda (real) em *javascript*?

O resultado está sendo **6.7** e não **6.70** (já tentei muitos exemplos aqui do fórum, mas nada ainda).

```js
function Calcular() {
  var valor1 = 3.35;
  var teste = Number(document.getElementById("teste").value);
  var result = document.getElementById("Resultado");
  if (result.textContent === undefined) {
    result.textContent = String(teste * valor1);
  } else { // IE
    result.innerText = String(teste * valor1);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="teste" name="teste" onkeyup="Calcular();" value="2">
<div id="Resultado"></div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O Cálculo você já faz, pelo que entendi o que você quer é mostrar o valor em 2 casas decimais, para isso, você pode utilizar o método [toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) do `JS`.

> O método toFixed() formata um número utilizando notação de ponto fixo.

```js
function Calcular() {
  var valor1 = 3.35;
  var teste = Number( document.getElementById( "teste" ).value);
  var result = document.getElementById( "Resultado" );
  if ( result.textContent === undefined ) {
    result.textContent =  (teste * valor1).toFixed(2);
  } else { // IE
    result.innerText =  (teste * valor1).toFixed(2);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="teste" name="teste" onkeyup="Calcular();" value="2" />

<div id="Resultado"></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Você deve informar ao `JavasSript` qual é a precisão da variável `Number` que você quer, usando o `toFixed`.

> OBS: `toFixed` irá transformar seu número em uma `string`.

Então ficaria assim:

```js
function Calcular() {
  var valor1 = 3.35;
  var teste = Number( document.getElementById( "teste" ).value);
  var result = document.getElementById( "Resultado" );
  
  /* Informando a precisão de 2 casas  */
  var valorFinal = (teste * valor1).toFixed(2);
  
  if ( result.textContent === undefined ) {
    result.textContent =  String( valorFinal );
  } else { // IE
    result.innerText =  String( valorFinal );
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="teste" name="teste" onkeyup="Calcular();" value="2">
<div id="Resultado"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Javascript possui um método [toFixed()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp) em que você pode determinar com quantas casas decimais você quer mostrar o seu valor